# How to rewrite a pair of nested for-loops as a comprehensive list expression

Tags: python

I'd like to make my code to be more Pythonic.

Having a simple list of lists like

```
numbers = [[1, 2], [3, 4, 5]]
```

I want to do this:

```
mylist = []
for sublist in numbers:
  for number in sublist:
      mylist.append(number)
```

But in a single line, using a comprehensive list definition:

```
mylist = [ number for number in  sublist for sublist in numbers]
```

However the result I get is [3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5]

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: you might mean 'pythonic' instead of 'pythonish'

Answer (score 11):

The order of the for loops is wrong – should be

```
mylist = [number for sublist in numbers for number in sublist]
```

instead.  People often find this surprising; just use the same order as you would in the nested `for` loop.

An alternative you could use is

```
from itertools import chain

mylist = list(chain.from_iterable(numbers))
```

Comment: Yep, that happend to me, I'll keep that memo-trick in mind. Thanks!

Comment: Another way to remember it: if you read from left to right then there should be no undefined (unbound) names in the for-loops i.e., `sublist` should be bound first; used later. Value area (`number` in this case) can use names defined anywhere.

Comment: +1 for "use the same order as you would in the nested for-loop" .. a good way to remember

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: I think the confusing thing about it is that `[f(i, j) for i in range(5) for j in range(5)]` and the flattened version of `[[f(i, j) for i in range(5)] for j in range(5)]` are different.

Answer (score 2):

I personally find nested list comprehensions difficult to read and understand. The `itertools` standard library has a handy `chain` function:

> `chain(*iterables) --> chain object`
>
> Return a chain object whose .next() method returns elements from the
>   first iterable until it is exhausted, then elements from the next
>   iterable, until all of the iterables are exhausted.

So you would do:

```
import itertools
mylist = list(itertools.chain(*numbers))
```

Comment: @AlbertoA. feel free to upvote if you found it useful, that's how SO works :)